# error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.50

Tags: r, linux, slurm

I try to submit a R script to SLURM in CentOS 7, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J test                   
#SBATCH -o test.out               
#SBATCH -p compute                
#SBATCH --qos=normal              
#SBATCH -N 1                      
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=8       
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1         
#SBATCH --job-name=rtest

Rscript --vanilla Rhelp.R
```

Then system will return a jobid, but the R script does not work. I can assure this script can run in command line. Then I have found in test.out, like this:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.50: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am a freshman in SLURM and Linux, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `libicu` RPM package is not installed on the compute nodes.

Comment: $ ldconfig -p | grep icu
        libicuuc.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libicuuc.so.50
        libicuuc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libicuuc.so
        libicutu.so.50 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libicutu.so.50

Comment: Does this code show that libicu PRM pacakage is already installed on the compute nodes？

Comment: Or more exactly run ``sudo dnf install libicuuc.so.60` (replace 60 with 50)

Answer (score 0):

Just because it may be installed on the head node doesn't mean it's installed on the compute node(s). You could fire off the same ldconfig command in a Slurm job and view the results to confirm that's the case.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your answer!.Now the scrcipt can run in SLURM, though I still don't know how to fix twhy it can now or can't before.

Comment: that's probably because you're loading a "module" or other environment-type parameter into your Slurm script that contains the path to libicuuc.so.50. Also check out the /etc/export file on the head node to see what is default exported for some hints, too

Answer (score 0):

With the `module avail` command from the head node you list all available modules and *loaded* modules are marked somehow depending on your OS; for me they are marked with (L). All you need to do is load those loaded modules from your file script each of which is invoked with the line
`module load path_to_module`. Whereas, `path_to_module` is as is indicated with the previous command `module avail`.
Or without resorting to `module avail` you could use `module list` for currently loaded modules.